# CMake building library and link to test code

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake

I'm quite new to CMake and I'm having some trouble getting it working the way I want.

My Project structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src/
|   ├── main.c
|   ├── main.h
|   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── include/
|   └── mylib.h 
├── test/
|   ├── test.cpp
|   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|   └── CMakeLists.txt.in
└── build/
```

What I want to do is to build a shared library `mylib` and then link it against a test target `example`, however it doesn't seem to link `mylib` agains the target `example`.

What I do is going in to the `build/` directory and do `cmake ..` which runs fine. I then proceed to `make` and run in to the problem:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
```

Down below is my files, the `CMakeLists.in.txt` is for pulling `gtest` which is working fine.

Cmake file in `src/`

```
set(SRC_FILES
  main.c
  main.h)

add_library(mylib SHARED ${SRC_FILES})
```

Cmake file in `test/`

```
...
add_executable(example test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example
  mylib
  gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)
```

(Gtest CMake code is omitted as that is not the problem)

CMake file in `.`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(cmake_hello)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

`mylib.h`

```
#ifndef LIB_HEADER_H_
#define LIB_HEADER_H_

#include "../src/main.h"

#endif
```

`main.c`

```
#include "main.h"

int add (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

`main.h`

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

int add(int a, int b);

#endif
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "../include/mylib.h"

TEST(example_test, test)
{
  int a = add(1,2);
  EXPECT_EQ(a,3);
}
```

Comment: You need to add `extern "C"` to the declaration of `add` in `main.h` so the C++ compiler will look for a symbol named "add" instead of the mangled `__Z3addii` or somesuch.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, this solved my problem. I'll accept this an answer if you write it.